# Extra characters in csv file

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm building a csv file and sending it to the browser. At some installs extra characters are added to the beginning of the body of the http response and it destroys the file.

This is what my code looks like.

```
Dim File As New Text.StringBuilder
File.Append("Batch Name,")
File.Append("Batch Accepted Total")
File.AppendLine

For Each Batch In Batches
    File.Append(Batch.Name)
    File.Append(",")
    File.AppendFormat("{0:c}", Batch.AcceptedTotal)

    File.AppendLine
Next

Dim FileName = "SomeFile.csv"
Dim Encoder = Text.Encoding.UTF8
Dim FileData = Encoder.GetBytes(File.ToString)

Response.Clear
Response.ClearHeaders
Response.Buffer = True
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & FileName)
Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
Response.OutputStream.Write(FileData, 0, FileData.Length)
Controller.FileData = Nothing
Response.Flush
Response.End
```

Only some installs do this, what others don't. I have no idea why. If I swap the databases the same site still has the problem. So I know it's not data dependent.

This is what the file ends up looking like

```
781
Batch Name,Batch Accepted Total
3/8/2013,$961.24
Lincoln Payroll,$999.99

0
```

The 718 on the first line changes. It seams to depend on the size of the file. The extra 0 on the end never changes, and I don't know where it comes from either.

**Update:**
I've discovered that the first line is the length of the intended content in hex. Also removing this line will remove the extra characters.

```
Response.Flush
```

I still do not know why. That line was not needed so I'm done looking for a fix, but if anybody has a clue about what was going on I would like to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

For a CSV, the Response.ContentType is "text/csv". Also, try using the [StreamWriter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter-vbnet) class to write the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess it has to do with the UTF8 encoding-- the last character is somehow special, maybe an EOF, then it gets encoded as 2 bytes and the receiver doesn't treat it as UTF8, but understands everything except the 2 byte character.  The receiver (notepad?) treats it as a 1byte per character encoding thing (maybe ordinary ascii).

Oh, I see your update. The spurious byte then must be shifting things around, enough to get a spurious final 0, but not enough to corrupt the whole file.

Last time I had to work with a file with a surprising encoding, I tried all the possible encodings-- some yielded completely messed up text, some were sort of readable and one was spot one.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved exactly the same issue in IIS 8.5 by disabling the Server rewrite rule from response header. The CSV with added lines and also broken PDF were made by SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services).